# Runtime error in python:lists

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, dynamic-programming

why is the following code giving runtime error
please suggest the reason, cant the arrays be indexed like c++

```
t=input()
dp1=[]
dp3=[]
dp5=[]
dp7=[]
dp1[0]=0
dp3[0]=0
dp5[0]=0
dp7[0]=0
dp1[1]=1
dp3[1]=1
dp5[1]=1
dp7[1]=1
i=2
while i<=10000:
    dp1[i]=dp3[i-1]
    dp5[i]=dp7[i-1]
    dp3[i]=dp1[i-1]+dp5[i-1]
    dp7[i]=dp5[i-1]+dp3[i-1]
    i+=1
while t>0:
    n=int(raw_input())
    print dp1[n]+dp3[n]+dp5[n]+dp7[n]
    t-=1
```

error message :Runtime error     time: 0.01 memory: 7852 signal:-1

Comment: No, python lists cannot be addressed arbitrarily. Use a dictionary if you need a sparse array, or initialize the whole list first.

Comment: - If you ask about errors, it makes sense to post the error message.

Comment: I am new to python, could u please suggest how shoud i change the above code so that it works

Comment: If you are running this on a code challenge website, run it *locally* first and give us the proper traceback. A *Runtime error* message is **not** enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Python lists do not auto-materialize indices.

If you want a dynamic programming scratchboard, set up the full lists:

```
dp1 = [0] * 1000
dp3 = [0] * 1000
dp5 = [0] * 1000
dp7 = [0] * 1000
```

or use `.append()`:

```
dp1 = [0, 1]
dp3 = [0, 1]
dp5 = [0, 1]
dp7 = [0, 1]

for i in xrange(2, 10001):
    dp1.append(dp3[i - 1])
    dp5.append(dp7[i - 1])
    dp3.append(dp1[i - 1] + dp5[i - 1])
    dp7.append(dp5[i - 1] + dp3[i - 1])

t = input()
for _ in xrange(int(t)):
    n = int(raw_input())
    print dp1[n] + dp3[n] + dp5[n] + dp7[n]
```

Here I used `for` loops over `xrange()` instead of a `while` loop to range through `i` and `t`.

Comment: Ok! is there some other way too?(just curious, though is is plain and simple that u told) thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
dp1[i]=dp3[i-1]
```

tries to read nonexistent  elements of dp3 for i>2. What's wrong is probably the loop from 2 to 10000.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want.

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.7

t=input()

dp1={0: 0, 1: 1}
dp3={0: 0, 1: 1}
dp5={0: 0, 1: 1}
dp7={0: 0, 1: 1}
for i in range (2, 10001):
    dp1[i]=dp3[i-1]
    dp5[i]=dp7[i-1]
    dp3[i]=dp1[i-1]+dp5[i-1]
    dp7[i]=dp5[i-1]+dp3[i-1]

while t>0:
    n=input()
    print dp1[n]+dp3[n]+dp5[n]+dp7[n]
    t-=1
```

Comment: Note that `i` ranges up without gaps, so this is not a sparse matrix. Lists are the better option here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I guess so. But maybe OP's next problem has sparse data and now he has seen a dict...